# I am finding this intermittent error: What does it mean?

Tags: python-2.7

My code is a solution of the subset sum:

```
import numpy as np

def subset_sum(theSet,target):
    n=len(theSet)    
    if(target==0):
        return np.empty([0]) #emptySet
    if(target<0 or n==0):
        return None
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target)
    if (theAuxSet!=None):
        return theAuxSet
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target-theSet[n-1]) 
    if(theAuxSet!=None):
        return np.append(theAuxSet,theSet[n-1])
    return None    



if __name__ == '__main__':

    theSet=np.array([8,6,7,5,3,10,9])
    target=15
    solution=[]
    print subset_sum(theSet,target)
```

The error below has happened. When the error does not happen, the code works as expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/Caju/UNB/Métodos de Análise Econômica - UNB/2016/Slides/Part I - Aula 10 Backtracking/subsetSum.py", line 25, in <module>
    subset_sum(theSet,target)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/Caju/UNB/Métodos de Análise Econômica - UNB/2016/Slides/Part I - Aula 10 Backtracking/subsetSum.py", line 10, in subset_sum
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/Caju/UNB/Métodos de Análise Econômica - UNB/2016/Slides/Part I - Aula 10 Backtracking/subsetSum.py", line 10, in subset_sum
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/Caju/UNB/Métodos de Análise Econômica - UNB/2016/Slides/Part I - Aula 10 Backtracking/subsetSum.py", line 10, in subset_sum
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/Caju/UNB/Métodos de Análise Econômica - UNB/2016/Slides/Part I - Aula 10 Backtracking/subsetSum.py", line 10, in subset_sum
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/Caju/UNB/Métodos de Análise Econômica - UNB/2016/Slides/Part I - Aula 10 Backtracking/subsetSum.py", line 13, in subset_sum
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target-theSet[n-1]) 
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/Caju/UNB/Métodos de Análise Econômica - UNB/2016/Slides/Part I - Aula 10 Backtracking/subsetSum.py", line 11, in subset_sum
    if (theAuxSet!=None):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 29, in _show_warning
    file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 119, in write
    self.old_stderr.write(colored_text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please see my answer to another question like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36536106/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xae-in-position-22/36536177#36536177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a numpy warning is causing this error. This is the warning I was able to find locally:

```
temp.py:13: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  if(theAuxSet!=None):
```

After refactoring like this:

```
def subset_sum(theSet,target):
    n=len(theSet)    
    if target==0:
        return np.empty([0]) #emptySet
    if target<0 or n==0:
        return None
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target)
    if theAuxSet is not None:
        return theAuxSet
    theAuxSet=subset_sum(theSet[0:n-1],target-theSet[n-1]) 
    if theAuxSet is not None:
        return np.append(theAuxSet,theSet[n-1])
    return None
```

The warning was gone.

Instead of using `a != None` you should use `a is not None`. This is a special case for `None` as it's a singleton. `is` checks by identity whereas `==` checks by comparison.

Comment: The error still persists... Even if I remove the print, the error is still there.

Comment: What unprintable characters you are talking about?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Updated my answer, tell me if it works.

Comment: thank you, but I still get the same problem! It is really strange! Warning about what?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Seems like it is a FutureWarning. Tested this code locally and it seems to work.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Btw, spyderlib causes the exception, but my code should eliminate the warning in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108768/discussion-between-bharel-and-danieltherocketman).